# ImportError: No module named sklearn.cluster in dbscan example

Tags: python

on Ubuntu 16.04 with Anaconda python 2.7, attempting http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html.  Getting import error: ImportError: No module named sklearn.cluster.  This is from the example code line: from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN.

I have scikit-learn installed via conda and all appears to be correct.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 6):

Did you install scikit-learn?

Make shure you already have a working installation of numpy and scipy

- Python (>= 2.6 or >= 3.3)
- NumPy (>= 1.6.1)
- SciPy (>= 0.9).

With pip (don't use it if you installed it with anaconda):

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

Or with condo:

```
conda install scikit-learn
```

Or try to upgrade scikit-learn (if you installed it with anaconda or conda)

```
conda update scikit-learn
```

You can find a detailed description here:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html

Comment: I believe that I have things in order; from "conda list":   python 2.7.12, NumPy 1.11.3, Scipy 0.18.1 - all installed via conda, using Anaconda python.

Comment: Try it with virtual environment: http://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/

Answer (score 0):

Try running the program explicitly like this:

```
$python3 your_program.py
```

Comment: running from the command line worked for me